# ¿Cómo hacer que el RIGHT JOIN retorne ceros?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

El día de hoy vengo con un pequeño problemilla con Bases de Datos, estoy usando `phpMyAdmin`, pero eso es lo de menos.

Tengo una tabla `marcaequipos`, donde almaceno marcas de equipos al azar, esta tabla esta compuesta por `IDMarca` y `NombreMarca`, nada más. Tengo otra tabla llamada `equipos` relacionada con la primera tabla por el `IDMarca`. En este caso, quiero saber el total de equipos por marca.

Realicé la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT m.NombreMarca, COUNT(*) as TotalPorMarca FROM equipos e 
RIGHT JOIN marcaequipos m ON e.IDMarca = m.IDMarca
GROUP BY m.IDMarca;
```

Está bien hecho y debería retornarme valores `null` o al menos ceros (0), sin embargo, me retorta unos (1) cuando se crea una marca nueva y esta aún **no tiene equipos asociados**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos deberían ser ceros (0), no sé por qué sucede esto. **¿Podrían ayudarme a resolverlo por favor?**

Comment: Intenta con `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Ya lo realicé de esa forma, pero no me retorna los ceros, solo me retorna las marcas que ya tienen asociado algún equipo, las que no, no aparecen :c

Comment: @DarwinCamiloFajardoBenitez Entonces, qué tal seleccionar desde la tabla `marcaequipos` realizando un (left) join con `equipos`, en vez de al revés? Si usas `from equipos` entonces claro que los marcos que no tienen ningún equipo asociado no aparecerán.

Comment: Es decir, así (?):

 `SELECT m.NombreMarca, COUNT(*) as TotalPorMarca FROM marcaequipos m 
LEFT JOIN equipos e ON e.IDMarca = m.IDMarca
GROUP BY m.IDMarca; `

Comment: Me retorna las que están vacías con unos (1)

Comment: @DarwinCamiloFajardoBenitez Bueno, tienes razón, he tenido que juguetear un poco con una tabla por mi propio cuenta para averiguar lo que está pasando. Échale un vistazo a mi respuesta abajo a ver si te parece :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vemos un pequeño ejemplo. Usamos el `LEFT JOIN` en vez de `RIGHT JOIN`. Aquí creamos las tablas:

```
create table marcaequipos ( 
  NombreMarca TEXT NOT NULL, 
  IDMarca INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);

create table equipos (
  NombreEquipo TEXT NOT NULL, 
  IDMarca INT NOT NULL, IDEquipo INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

Y aquí añadimos algunas entradas de prueba:

```
insert into marcaequipos (NombreMarca, IDMarca) 
                  values ("Prueba 1", 1);

insert into marcaequipos (NombreMarca, IDMarca) 
                  values ("Prueba 2", 2);

 insert into equipos (NombreEquipo, IDMarca, IDEquipo) 
              values ("Equipo A", 1, 1);

insert into equipos (NombreEquipo, IDMarca, IDEquipo) 
             values ("Equipo B", 1, 2);

insert into equipos (NombreEquipo, IDMarca, IDEquipo) 
             values ("Equipo C", 1, 3);
```

Fíjate que el equipo `Prueba 2` no tiene ningunos equipos asociados. Probamos el orden siguiente:

```
select marcaequipos.NombreMarca, COUNT(equipos.IDMarca) 
  from marcaequipos left join equipos 
  on marcaequipos.IDMarca = equipos.IDMarca 
  group by equipos.IDMarca;
```

y produce la salida siguiente:

```
Prueba 2|0
Prueba 1|3
```

... que me parece lo que quieres, ¿no?

Para averiguar por qué tu orden produce `1` en vez de `0` para las filas de marcas sin ningún equipo, probamos el orden siguiente:

```
select * 
  from marcaequipos left join equipos 
  on marcaequipos.IDMarca = equipos.IDMarca;
```

que imprime la tabla

```
Prueba 1|1|Equipo A|1|1
Prueba 1|1|Equipo B|1|2
Prueba 1|1|Equipo C|1|3
Prueba 2|2|||
```

Nota la fila al final que está asociada a la marca `Prueba 2` aunque ésta no tiene ningún equipo asociado. Esto me parece una particularidad del `LEFT JOIN` (aunque si hay alguna motivación para este comportamiento, no la sé y me interesaría saberla). Pero de todos modos, cuando realizas un `COUNT(*)` entonces estás incluyendo esta fila "trivial", pero realizando un `COUNT(equipos.IDMarca)` puedes excluirla.

Comment: Brother, nunca se me ocurrió que fuera por esa orden. Interesante, muchísimas gracias por tu aporte, eres un crack, eso solucionó mi problema :D MUCHAS GRACIASSSS!!